# How to calculate the average velocity over the flowpath length?

Tags: arcmap

I’m working on building a GIS based groundwater travel time distribution (TTD) model similar to the one developed by Schilling and Wolter (2007)
http://lilt.ilstu.edu/ewpeter/GEO435/Readings/2012/Schilling_Kelly.pdf.

The conceptual model of cell TTD is illustrated below (Schilling and Wolter, 2007). 
[image]

As you know
Velocity = -k (dh/dl)/n

I have calculated the velocity using raster calculator. I used the permeability values  from the soil map as a substitute for hydraulic conductivity, the slope from the DEM as substitute for hydraulic gradient (dh/dl) and porosity (n) one value only from literature. I calculated the distance till the nearest river using Euclidean Distance.

After getting the velocity and the distance, I can easily calculate the time using raster calculator. However, it is not straightforward like this. Schilling & Wolter (2007) described how to calculate the time as follows “The time needed for groundwater in each 5-m cell to travel from the cell to the stream network was then determined by averaging all the individual cell velocities over the ﬂowpath length from the cell to the stream”

[image]

**So, in order to calculate the time, I have to calculate the average velocities over the flowpath length which I don’t know how to do.** It would be much appreciated if you can help me in this regard.

Comment: Your work appears inconsistent. If you truly calculated velocity (not just speed), you can see that the groundwater rarely flows in a straight line towards its discharge point. Thus the Euclidean distance has little relevance. You need to track the flow down flow lines instead and, at each cell, record the cumulative time and cumulative distance from the discharge point. That's what Schilling & Wolter are saying. (BTW, this is not an average *velocity*, it's an average *speed*.) You can adapt a costdistance or pathdistance calculation to do this.

Comment: @whuber Many thanks for your help and detailed reply. I do agree with you the Euclidean distance was not the right choice. What about using the flow length to calculate the distance and using the flow accumulation as the weight raster with a null value for the river network (i.e. cells with flow accumulation values >=100000 for example)? It would be much appreciated if you can explain in more detail how can I use cost distance and path distance to calculate the travel time?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the flowpaths identified and a velocity surface, perhaps zonal statistics could work for you. The tool calculates statistics (mean, median, etc.,) on values of a raster within the zones of another dataset. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000

Comment: If you need to identify groundwater flowpaths, and Euclidean distance is appropriate, you could use Near (Analysis) to determine flowpath of a source to the nearest point of the river.

Comment: In general that will not work unless the "source" is very close to the river, because Euclidean distance is not appropriate.

Comment: @whuber I agree, but I saw above that Euclidean was used to get the distance to stream. I have only used cost or path distance for this type of analysis - but I have only worked with surface - and not with groundwater.

Comment: Your experience with surface water flow is applicable here, because the model the OP uses is so greatly simplified that it is *identical* to a surface water flow model.  (The model is two dimensional, flow is advective only, the hydraulic gradient equals the topographic gradient, the porosity is constant, and--although this is not stated--the transmissivity tensor is isotropic.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks for looking at the whole question, and for your detailed explanation. Obviously it wasn't my question, but it's great to learn/think about.

Comment: @mwil Thanks for your answer, time and help. I don't have the flow paths. I think, however, I can create them using the flow accumulation map and the following expression in raster calculator con(("fac">100) & ("fac"<100000), 0, 1). Please correct me if I'm wrong. I think this expression will create a raster map in which all the paths have a value of 1 and all other cells have 0 value. After getting the flow paths, I don't know how I'll identify each flowpath to calculate its average velocity. Any help would be appreciated.